# List display inline text text-overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a list of element displayed inline with a `text-overflow : ellipsis`. But after several attempt I cannot make the text-overflow working it still making a clip instead of ellipsis

ps : This div can be resized that explain the `text-align : center`

```css
div {
   position: relative;
   left: 100px;
   width: 175px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow : hidden;
   text-overflow : ellipsis;
}

ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text that will overflow</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Crema/xg29zmz8/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to apply `display:inline` on the `ul` and `li`:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text that will overflow</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>some text</li>
        <li>some text that will overflow</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am also having the doubt .This code is very useful for me that is working